# precompile globals (variables, mixins etc.) with grunt-sass/node-sass

Tags: css, dependency-injection, sass, gruntjs

i'm using grunt-sass/node-sass for compiling my scss files.
i have a lot of scss-files like btn.scss, panel.scss etc. component like.

i'm NOT mergin all scss files in one big css file (styles.css) - instead I compile like all separated css files (btn.css, panel.css etc.)

because I have globals scss files like variables.scss, mixins.scss etc. I have to import these files in every single scss file. for example in btn.scss I need to write everytime the @import directive (ex. @import 'variables, @import mixing etc.'). of course I could merge all globals files in one file and the just import that file.

is there a more elegant way to precomile or to inject these global files before or while compiling with grunt-sass?

thx!

Comment: You could create a global.scss file which contains all your other imports and import that.

Comment: thx for the answer. i wrote that, i could do that...i'm searching a solution to bypass the @import in every scss - i want to do this process while (or before) compiling with a task manager (grunt, gulp or whatever).